# FoxPro Conditional Sum Statement

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am trying to perform a conditional sum on a column of data in a FoxPro program. I think it should be able to be done in one line or so. So far I have something that looks like:

```
public sumvar
sumvar = SUM(TABLE2.val WHERE table2.id = table1.id)
```

This is being done inside a loop, so for this instance, table1.id might equal 4, and there are say 3 rows in table2 which have table2.id = 4. So I want to sum the table2.val value for just these 3 rows together. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend the SQL way rather than the xBase Sum command

```
CLEAR

CREATE CURSOR test (id Int, amount N(15,2))
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 15.45)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 8)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 9)
GO TOP IN test

* SQL
LOCAL ARRAY laSum[1]
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM test WHERE id = 1 INTO ARRAY laSum
? laSum[1]

* xBase
SUM amount FOR id = 1 TO result
? m.result
* F1 Help says: "Totals all or specified numeric fields in the **currently selected table**"
```

Another disadvantage of the xBase command would be moving record pointers.

Comment: That worked nicely. Thanks a ton Stefan.